# Weapon DPS changed after importing from Diablo 3 vanilla to UEE

Tags: diablo-iii-console

I have imported my save from Diablo 3 vanilla (PS3) to UEE (XOne), after which I've noticed a few weapon's DPS display numbers have changed. It seems weapons with high ED% got nerf'ed. I've searched a few forums without seeing this being mentioned. Although these lv63 weapons will be irrelevant in UEE, I still want to understand what's going on. My questions are,

1. Is the difference caused by DPS formula change? What exactly is it?
2. Is it just a visual change of how DPS number is displayed, or an actual change to the damage output?
3. Or is it a bug with the game or my save file?

Comment: Not sure about console, but on PC in vanilla Diablo 3 IIRC DPS wasn't computed correctly for weapons with elemental damage (I think, it's been a while). Maybe that's what you're seeing here?

Comment: @Adeese the formulas are still not accurately showing in PC.  Ihave a monk who hits 1.2 M and has 9M Toughness but will get one shotted in T6.  Oh and 50k life per hit.